# Two subplots Within a Single Plot in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

After a count operation in Pandas, I have the following dataframe:

```
Cancer                  No   Yes
AgeGroups Factor                
0-5       w-statin     108     0
          wo-statin   6575   223
11-15     w-statin       5     1
          wo-statin   3669   143
16-20     w-statin      28     1
          wo-statin   6174   395
21-25     w-statin      80     2
          wo-statin   8173   624
26-30     w-statin     110     2
          wo-statin   9143   968
30-35     w-statin     171     5
          wo-statin   9046  1225
35-40     w-statin     338    21
          wo-statin   8883  1475
41-45     w-statin     782    65
          wo-statin  11155  2533
```

I am having a problem with my barchart. With the code:

```
ax = counts.plot(kind='bar',stacked=True,colormap='Paired',rot = 45)

for p in ax.patches:
        ax.annotate(np.round(p.get_height(),decimals=0).astype(np.int64), (p.get_x()+p.get_width()/2., p.get_y()), ha='center', va='center', xytext=(2, 10), textcoords='offset points', fontsize=10)
```

yielded me: 
[image]

My target is to achieve two different subplots with two different factors (w-statin/wo-statin) with agegroups as my x-axis. It should approximately look like this:
[image]

I would appreciate any help provided. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
by_factor = counts.groupby(level='Factor')

k = by_factor.ngroups

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, k, sharex=True, sharey=False, figsize=(15, 8))
for i, (gname, grp) in enumerate(by_factor):
    grp.xs(gname, level='Factor').plot.bar(
        stacked=True, colormap='Paired', rot=45, ax=axes[i], title=gname)
fig.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Comment: First of all thank you piRSquared for your answer. At the first glance, I thought , I understood it. Could you please explain to me 'k' and 'by_factor' parameters ? Thank you so much for your time and help.

Comment: @Aceraceae so glad you asked... I didn't paste all the code... I really should get some sleep.  Will edit post.

Comment: Okay. Take your time and thank you so much for replying.